# delphi splash form doesn't fire timer events if shown non-modally

Tags: delphi, timer, splash-screen, non-modal

I have coded a splash form that fades in, shows for a while, then fades out.  The fading is implemented with a timer which closes the form also. It works fine.

I was showing the form modally, but I suspected that the main form wasn't starting to construct and showing until after the splash form was closed.

Then I figured that if I showed the form non-modally and used fsStayOnTop (i.e. SplashForm.Show instead of SplashForm.ShowModal) then the main form could initialise behind the splash form as soon as the splash form was shown, meaning the app was ready to go when the splash form closed.

I find however that the timer event doesn't fire anymore.  Nor does a TApplication.OnIdle event.  What gives?

Comment: don't `fsStayOnTop`; people want to use other apps while your app is loading. No app is not that special that it should prevent that! (The Old New Thing explains quite nicely that no app is special: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/20/9435239.aspx)

Comment: I guess it was a blunt force way of ensuring that the splash screen didn't get hidden by the main form, which would defeat the purpose.  On the other hand, I don't want the main form to be placed behind other running apps, so how do I keep the splash form in front of the app main window?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say this is a splash screen.  Is it being shown during program startup, before you've hit the line `Application.Run;` in the DPR?  If so, then the TApplication event loop hasn't started yet, so you won't get any OnIdle events.

Comment: Yes, it's called as the first thing in the DPR body.  If the splash form is shown modally, the timer and TApplicationEvents seem to fire OK.

Comment: @user89691: Yeah, I think ShowModal either has its own event loop or does something to kickstart the Application event loop.  Either way, you're not going to get timer events to fire without the event loop running, which normally gets started by calling `Application.Run`

Comment: Hmmmm. So do I conclude from this that I can't get a form to show non-modally before the main form?  I guess my question should have been: "How do I get a splash form to show as early as possible after application startup and let initialisation continue the application main form show while the splash form is showing"  Other apps seem to manage to do it.

Comment: ShowModal() runs its own message loop internally, since the calling thread's message loop is blocked until ShowModal() exits.

Comment: @user89691: you can display a non-modal form before calling Application.Run(). Simply call TForm.Update() after calling TForm.Show(). Just don't rely on any functionality that is dependant on message processing, such as timers, since the message loop is not running yet.

Answer (score 2):

Fade will not work with standard Timers because application loop will not function until you call Application.Run (as said by Mason), and timers are wrappers for a message based timer API mechanism.

You can't use thread based timers, because it will require Synchronize to work with the UI and Synchronize is message based mechanism.

But you can *waste* the time required to fade-in/fade out, so you could get a fancy application start and if you're looking for this I freely consider you're not worried about wasting a bit of time.  I can explain a lot better with (working and tested) code example, so this will work for you:

USplashForm.pas:

```
//...
interface
//...
type
  TSplashForm = class(TForm)
    //...
  public
    procedure FadeIn;
    procedure FadeOut;
    //...
  end;

//...
implementation
//...
procedure TSplashForm.FadeIn;
begin
  AlphaBlend := True;
  AlphaBlendValue := 0;
  Show;
  Update;
  repeat
    AlphaBlendValue := AlphaBlendValue + 5;
    Update;
    Sleep(20);
  until AlphaBlendValue >= 255;
end;

procedure TSplashForm.FadeOut;
begin
  repeat
    AlphaBlendValue := AlphaBlendValue - 5;
    Update;
    Sleep(20);
  until AlphaBlendValue <= 5;
  Hide;
end;
//...
```

YourProject.dpr

```
var
  Splash: TSplashForm;

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Splash := TSplashForm.Create(nil);
  try
    Splash.FadeIn;
    //any initialization code here!!!
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
    MainForm.Show;
    MainForm.Update;
    //more code
    Sleep(500);  //I used it to delay a bit, because I only create one form and I have not initialization code at all!
    Splash.FadeOut;
  finally
    Splash.Free;
  end;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

My 5 cents, enjoy.

Comment: the TThread.Synchronize() method has not been message-based since D5.  In D6, it was re-written to not use messages anymore (well, not for the actual method call, anyway - it does post a WM_NULL message to "wake up" the main thread).  In D6 and later, if the message loop has not begun running yet, your code can manually call CheckSynchronize() periodically (such as during the MainForm's startup code) to allow Tthread.Synchronize() requests to be processed.

Comment: @Remy: I'm obviously outdated about not using messages anymore in Synchronize method.  Anyway, if you have to check CheckSynchronize periodically, for this particular case, the fade may not work as nice as someone would want (for example I).  Using my method is still valid for what @User89691 wants, which I think is a nice visual effect (which is of course valid!)

Answer (score 1):

I have done it in the following way:

- I removed the splash form from the "Auto-create forms".
- In the `FormCreate` of the main form I have:

  ```
  with TfSplash.Create(Self) do Show;
  ```
- And in the splash form I have the following:

  ```
  procedure TfSplash.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Timer.Enabled:=True;
  end;


  procedure TfSplash.TimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    Release; // like free, but waits for events termination
  end;
  ```

Comment: The downside to this approach is that the MainForm's OnCreate event is not fired until after DFM streaming has occured.  If the form has a lot of controls on it, or they take awhile to initialize, then the splash form will not appear right away.

Comment: ...which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.  Optimally - I would want a splash screen to pop up more or less instantly, so that the user has a bit of eye candy to chew on while the main form is streamed.  I guess one way would be to do it with 2 separate apps.  App1 would do nothing more than display the splash screen, then exec App2 - the main app.  App1 would then close after a delay.